# LinQ & DataTable Group By Question in C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, group-by

I have a DataTable and stores 4 columns (StockCardCode,Explain,Quantity,BranchCode), and Im grouping them with a LinQ. Code is my key for using Group By. When I write my query, I just can use 2 columns in select statement, how can I show all columns in this query? This query returns me 2 column. I cant use x.Field("Explain") in my query for example.

```
var query = from s in incoming.AsEnumerable()
                        group s by s.Field<string>("Stock Card Code")
                            into grp
                            orderby grp.Key
                            select new { StockCardCode = grp.Key, Quantity = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Quantity")) };
```

**incoming: DataTable**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are grouping by StockCardQuote, the "Explain" value is going to be all of the Explain values from rows with the same StockCardQuote -- it is going to be an `IEnumerable<T>`, so if Explain is a `string`, you'll get `IEnumerable<string>`.

To include this in your `select` statement, just do

```
select new { 
    StockCardCode = grp.Key, 
    Quantity = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Quantity")),
    Explanations = grp.Select(r => r.Field<string>("Explain")) };
```

Comment: Yes I get IEnumerable<T>, then how can I get my required string?

Comment: What string are you looking for? For any given `StockCardCode` there may be multiple `Explain` values. Perhaps it is not grouping that you want to do…

Comment: Then you can do as Saeed suggested: take the first of the `IEnumerable<string>` and get the `Explain` from that: `Explain = grp.First().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Explain"))`

Answer (score 3):

There is no unique item in your group but you can select the first item and show the fields:

```
    select 
    new { StockCardCode = grp.Key, 
    Quantity = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Quantity")),
    Explain = grp.First().Select(x=>x.Field<string>("Explain"))}
```